# Upload on Specific Path on dropbox in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dropbox

I need to upload on a specific folder in dropbox using vb.net api how I do it? Here is an example I made a folder using the username (John) on dropbox in folder john I made another folder named photos now I want to upload their every photo in John/photos how I do that? Remember Every user has different folders and every folder has different photos subfolder

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial the example right at the bottom shows how to target a specific folder. Quite simple - just concatenate the folder name. Try actually reading the documentation and examples.

Comment: But there is not a proper example that i want in my case default photo save path is username/picture and i want to arrange same as my client's computer in their dropbox

Comment: ??? Just set the folder name to whatever you need it to be. If you need to use some logic determine the correct folder name to use, that's a separate issue. Are you saying that you want to query the user's Dropbox account to find out where their photo folder is?

Comment: Actually I have to make folder in his dropbox i done that thing but now i want upload his pictures in that folder

Comment: so the example I gave shows clearly how to do it. `folder + "/" + file`. Just set `folder` to your folder name. If it's a series of subfolders, then it's a string with multiple `/` in it. I'm not sure why this is causing you a problem?

Comment: I'm Done Thank you so much ADyson ;'). I do "/Foldername/" &  Path.GetFileName(full_path of that file) and I'm done

Comment: "guys". I'm only one person lol :-). I hope in future you can learn to do your own research and read all the documentation :-). It will save you a lot of time

Comment: Sorry and Thank you :)